# Java - Separate and display element from ArrayList like list with sub-list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, printing

I have a car class with attributes `Manufacturer` and `Model`. A `Manufacturer` can have many `Model`, for example manufacturer `Chevrolet` have models such as `Camaro`, `Malibu`... I create an `ArrayList` to store them, something like this:

```
Cars objCar;
ArrayList<Cars> arrListCars;

objCar = new Cars("Chevrolet","Camaro");
arrListCars.add(objCar);
objCar = new Cars("Chevrolet","Malibu");
arrListCars.add(objCar);
objCar = new Cars("Ford","Mustang");
arrListCars.add(objCar);
objCar = new Cars("Ford","Fiesta");
arrListCars.add(objCar);
```

I can print and display a list like:

```
Manufacturer: Chevrolet | Model: Camaro
Manufacturer: Chevrolet | Model: Malibu
Manufacturer: Ford | Model: Mustang
Manufacturer: Ford | Model: Fiesta
```

But I want to display something like this:

```
Manufacturer: Chevrolet | Model: Camaro Malibu
Manufacturer: Ford | Model: Mustang Fiesta
```

I have getter setter in the car class.

Please help, I'm new to java and really don't know how to pick out element like that, thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that's trivial with a loop. You should be able to do this on your own with a bit of Googling. Don't be lazy to learn stuff :)

Comment: I know it will need to use loop, but I don't know how the model can seperate but still of the same manufacture. I can take out the manufacturer without duplicate using a List, but 2 element at the same time, I'm quite stuck...

Comment: Your expected output wasn't complete enough, the edit makes it clearer. Now it's less trivial for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

So one way you can do this is by using getters. I assume that in your Cars class you probably have the variables Manufacturer and Model. Strings. As such I assume it is

```
private String manufacturer;
private String model

public Cars(String manufacturer, String model) {
this.manufacturer = manu;
this.model = model;
}
```

Now, within that class you can create getters.

```
public String getManufacturer() {
return manufacturer;
}

public String getModel() {
return model;
}
```

So now you have access to your inner data variables.

Inside your main code, after you have added your cars to the list you can access them (and print them in the format you want as follows:

```
for(Car cars: arrListCars) {
System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + cars.getManufacturer() + "| Model: " + cars.getModel());
}
```

The above for loop is a for-each example. Another way to use the for loop, in a more traditional way that you may be familiar with is the indexed for loop. Ex:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrListCars.size(); i++) {
System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + arrListCars.get(i).getManufacturer() + "| Model: " + arrListCars.get(i).getModel());
}
```

**EDIT**

I see, so you want to make it unified. Okay, for that you will need to use a Map. Quick explanation of Maps. Maps map Object Keys to Object Values, usually shown as Map in the IDE (say like Eclipse). As such in your code you will need to add those values to the Map.

Ex:

Map carMap = new HashMap<>();

carMap.put("Ford","Mustang");
carMap.put("Chevy,"Tahoe");

Then within your code you can create an intermediate String. Ex:

```
String chevyManu = "Manufacturer: Chevrolet | ";
String fordManu = "Manufacturer: Ford | ";

for (String key : carMap.keySet()) {
   if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("Ford") {
       fordManu += carMap.get(key);
   }
   else if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("Chevrolet") {
             chevyManu += carMap.get(key);
   }
}
```

I had to look up how to iterate over a map, I used http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-traverse-or-loop-hashmap-in-java.html as my source.

**EDIT 2**

Thinking over it, I think you can actually avoid using Maps as well. We will still use the idea of having the two Strings (chevyManu and fordManu) and first initialize them to "Manufacturer: Chevrolet or Ford | ", then inside the code that loops over the array we can create some basic if statements.

Ex:

```
for(Car cars: arrListCars) {
if(cars.getManufacturer().equalsIgnoreCase("Chevrolet") {
chevyManu += cars.getModel() + " ";
}
else if(cars.getManufacturer().equalsIgnoreCase("Ford") {
fordManu += cars.getModel() + " ";
}
}
```

Idea here being to leverage what you already have and try to avoid added complexity. I hope this helped :)

Comment: In my opinion it was unnecessary to answer in this case. One minute of Googling would have told him the answer straight away.

Comment: Possibly so, however I think showing him a for-each loop -- something a beginner may not know is valid. Also, I was thinking of adding another edit to show him how to avoid using getters by making the variables public

Comment: That way, each line repeat the same manufacturer. But in this case, I want to show the list with just one manufacturer and all of its model, in the same line, like : Manufacturer: Ford | Model: Mustang, Fiesta, and more...

Comment: Hello, can you review my edited question and get what I'm trying to ask. It's not that I don't know the basic loop, but this one get a bit more complicated with the difference elements but not duplicate within an arraylist. That's why I asked.

Comment: Ah, so you want to make it unified together. Gotcha.

Comment: Check out the latest edits when you get the chance :)

Comment: Ok, I appreciated your help very much, I'm trying to understand how to use this into my project. Thanks you.

Comment: Let me know if you need help trying to integrate it.

Comment: @SomeStudent the answer needs some formatting, but using a map makes it more efficient than Arthur's. I think your answer could be shorter as well, not everything in it is useful. Finally, you don't need to have **EDIT** notes. You would do that only if your answer had stayed here for years and you had an update to make, but here you just edited it right now so you should just provide a nice, short and consistent answer. No need to patch it with various edits

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the pointers. I guess first part of answer might be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I have some untested code that might help:

```
public void getAllCarsWithManufacturer(String manufacturer, List<Cars> cars, List<Cars> out){
    for (Cars car : cars){
        // make sure manufacturer matches the one that we need
        if (car.getManufacturer().equals(manufacturer)){
            // add car to output list
            out.add(car);
        }
    }
}

public void printOutAllCarsWithManufacturer(String manufacturer, List<Cars> library, List<Cars> out){
    // empty the list we are using to output the info
    out.clear();
    // fill the out with the correct manufacturer
    getAllCarsWithManufacturer(manufacturer, library, out);
    // print out the data
    System.out.println("manufacturer: "+manufacturer + " | " + out.toString());
}

public void printOutAllCars(List<Cars> cars){
    // sets cant have duplicates
    HashSet<String> nodupcars = new HashSet<String>();
    List<Cars> out = new ArrayList<Cars>();
    // use the nodupcars to watch manufacturers
    for (Cars car : cars){
        nodupcars.add(car.getManufacturer());
    }
    for (String car : nodupcars){
        printOutAllCarsWithManufacturer(car, cars, out);
    }
}
```

You would use `printOutAllCars()` to show all the cars based on manufacturer. This is also assuming that `Cars` has some sort of `getManufacturer()` method to retrieve the manufacturer.

Comment: I'll have a try on that, still figuring out what's all that mean, but thanks a bunch !

Comment: @TriLuong if it works make sure to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: That's a complicated way to do it, as well as inefficient. Plus, accumulators (your `out` variable) are anti-pattern in Java, where you prefer returning a result rather than modifying your arguments